# Formula for current through an edge in terms of sums over spanning trees

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, spanning-tree

Please help me find a link to the proof of the following theorem (w(T) denotes the weight of the tree T):

Consider an electric circuit with two boundary vertices $a$ and $b$.
Current through the edge $\rho$ is equal to $I_{\rho} 
=\frac{\sum w(T_{+}) -\sum w(T_{-})}{\sum w(T)},$

where the sum in the denominator is over all spanning trees $T$ and the sums in the numerator is over all spanning trees $T_{+}$ /$T_{-}$, where on the path from $a$ to $b$ the edge $\rho$ appears with positive / negative orientation, respectively.

Comment: Is this Theorem 3.7 of https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/snell.pdf ?